# NHibernate: Select entire entity plus aggregate columns

Tags: nhibernate

I want to return an entire entity, along with some aggregate columns. In SQL I would use an inner select, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 f.*, inner_query.[average xxx]
FROM (
      SELECT f.Id, AVG(fb.xxx) AS [average xxx]
      FROM foobar fb
      INNER JOIN foo f ON f.FoobarId = fb.Id
     ) AS inner_query
INNER JOIN foo f ON f.Id = inner_query.Id
```

Is this possible with CreateCriteria?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a formula property to the entity: [see #5 on this list](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/07/nhibernate-mapping-ltpropertygt.aspx).